# wstool, rosinstall, rosws difference

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are the main differences among these packages ?

It seems **rosws** replaces **rosinstall** but what about **wstool** ?

Is one of them recommended for catkin ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227665/wstool,-rosinstall,-rosws-difference/) by [thomio](https://answers.ros.org/users/25877/thomio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, [wstool](http://wiki.ros.org/wstool) replaces rosws. See the link for details about that. And both rosws and wstool use [rosinstall files](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosinstall/html/rosinstall_file_format.html) for configuring workspaces. In general I have only seen wstool used with catkin workspaces and would recommend you use wstool instead of rosws.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2016-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thomio](https://answers.ros.org/users/25877/thomio/) on 2016-02-29**:
Thanks for the links. It appears wstool is the final tool to manage src pkgs. FYI [rosinstall](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosinstall/html/rosws.html) is also a terminal cmd. The funny fact is that all these 3 cmds have the same functions.